# Does the use of the symbol slash for "or" come from the use of "|" in computer programming?

Tags: etymology, punctuation, symbols, slash

Does the rise of acceptance in "/" for "or" come from the use of "|" in computer programming (For "OR")?

If not is there any correlation?

Comment: As someone who extensively uses /, I'm certain it has nothing to do with logical |.

Comment: No. Slash has been used this way long before people programmed computers.

Comment: The use of "/" for "or" is longstanding.  In fact, [and/or](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72369/is-there-a-symbol-for-and-or) has, for as long as I can remember, been quite common as a substitution for `"and" or "or"`.

Comment: (Though it's likely that the use of "|" for "OR" in math and programming was influenced by the use of "/" in English.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: Because "/" was already taken for division.  Though strictly speaking, what we normally think of as or is "||" (at least in C and its derivatives), while "|" is a bitwise or.

Comment: The slash is also increasing used in place of "and," as well as  in place of commas. Certainly does seem to be increasing.

Comment: @james Matlab/Octave uses | for logical OR.

Comment: @A.S. was your example deliberate? It's a rather nice example. In terms of grammatical number "/" must function as "or", but the sense is more like "and".

Comment: No, @Chris, my example was completely accidental  and incidental but it indeed exhibits the customary "and/or" sense - combining objects of similar/close properties. I wouldn't use "/" to combine (wildly) different categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of *computer programming* includes at least formal logic, circuit design, and the use of modern programming languages. For simplicity, I'll just take [Babbage's difference engine of 1822](http://cs.brown.edu/~adf/programming_languages.html) as a convenient starting date for the sake of comparison.

In English, the virgule dates back to the mid 19th century according to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virgule), so may be argued to start around the same time as computer programming. However, it traces its etymology to usage "as a comma medieval MSS" ([etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=virgule)). Arguably, the concept of disjunction was already inherent in this usage.

Note that "/" isn't always simply a logical *or* in English. An example from [thepunctuationguide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) is *office/dining room*, in which "/" is equivalent to the Latin preposition *cum*, as in *office-*cum*-dining room", where it has an element of conjunction. Compare the Latin phrase *summa cum laude* - it isn't simply *best* or *praised* - it's both (excuse my poor Latin).

The vertical bar as *disjunction* in computer programming can be traced back to the Backus-Naur Form (follow the links in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057182/4983400)) from [about 1958 or 1959](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (see also [ALGOL 58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_58)), where [the vertical bar represents *choice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#History). Here's an example of such an expression:

> digit ::= "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"

So there seems to be little correlation between the etymology of the disjunctive "/" in English and that of computer programming's "|", other than perhaps that both are particularly visual representations of some kind of list separator.

Comment: Do you know why is inclusive OR called *dis*junction which upon naive reading would mean exclusive OR (i.e. XOR). *Con*junction seems like a better choice for OR.

Comment: @A.S. I don't know for sure, but if you go back through the earlier maths of set theory and Venn diagrams, the notion of conjunction (*and*) was already formalised as intersection. The truth-table definition of the *logical and* already had this background, leaving set union for the *inclusive or* / disjunction. Note that *exclusive or* doesn't quite map as nicely to *set union*, and the mathematical discipline of *logic* likely had greater weight than English semantics in the definition of programming's *and* and *or*.

Comment: Having looked up detailed definition of conjunction, it seems like an OK, if somewhat ambiguous, choice for AND. But I'm still bothered by math/logician's choice of *dis*junction for inclusive OR since *dis* doesn't resonate with "inclusion" at all and resonates well with XOR (which is equal to the union of two *dis*joint sets A\B and B\A). Most "lay terms" for mathematical objects do correlate at least slightly with English semantics - or at least don't contradict it.

Comment: @A.S. Perhaps this is an instance of a semantic shift of sorts: *separate* to *split* to *choice* to *aggregate*. The set-union understanding of logical disjunction has the notion of an *aggregate* of the various *choices*. As you say, the plain English word *disjoint* has the opposite sense.